# Using Waitable Timers with an Asynchronous Procedure Call

Tags: c++, winapi

I have used MSDN's example from [Using Waitable Timers with an Asynchronous Procedure Call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/using-a-waitable-timer-with-an-asynchronous-procedure-call) to check how APC works in action. However, when I try to compile this source code, it doesn't compile, it gives me the following error:

> C4700: uninitialized local variable 'MyData' used

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: (Looking at the link, but next time please paste the code into your question as text).  _What is wrong with this code_ Nothing, so far as I can see.  What version of the compiler are you using?

Comment: wrong that after `CloseHandle( hTimer )` need call `SleepEx(0, TRUE);` or `NtTestAlert();` in order to ensure that there are no more APC in the thread queue from the timer. but you must not got *error C4700* here if not make errors by self

Comment: There is no *uninitialized* `MyData` variable in the example, so the error is clearly due to something you added that we can't see. Please [edit] your question to show YOUR actual code, not some example code on an external site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the sample in the link directly in C++, the following code will have an error (because C++ strictly matches the type of string).

```
MyData.szText = TEXT("This is my data");
```

> C2440 '=': cannot convert from 'const wchar_t [16]' to 'TCHAR *'

So maybe you use the `lstrcpy` (or `strcpy`) function like this:

```
lstrcpy(MyData.szText, TEXT("This is my data"));
```

This will trigger a C4700 error:

> C4700: uninitialized local variable 'MyData' used

You can just try to use cast and it works for me:

```
MyData.szText = (TCHAR *)TEXT("This is my data");
```

Comment: Your suggestion to use `lstrcpy()` won't work unless you first assign `szText` to point at a valid buffer for `lstrcpy()` to copy into, eg: `TCHAR buffer[256]; MyData.szText = buffer; lstrcpy(MyData.szText, ...);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I mean using the `lstrcpy()` function will cause C4700 error.My presentation problem, sorry.